# iterating array of objects and the key values in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects

`var j = [{"v1":["1","2","3"]}, {"v2":["4","5","6"]}, {"v3":["7","8","9"]}];`

I want to check against the object property and perform some sort of logic. I am new to JS so I'm not sure of all the methods I have access to. Basically I want to compare the key value of the object to a string. If the key and the string are the same, then I would remove that object from the array. I'm not sure how to iterate through the object's key in the array.

```
var str = "v1";
for (var i in j) {
  if (i.key == str) {     // not sure how to access key value
    j.splice(i,1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Look into [for loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) (for the array) and [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) (for the objects).

Comment: You should never iterate an array with `for (var i in j)` because that iterates all enumerable properties of the array, not just array elements.  You can use either `for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++)` or you can use `j.forEach(function(val, index) {...})`.  The construct `for (var i in j)` is used to iterate all properties of an object.

Comment: Whenever I see this sort of data structure, I always wonder if the data structure is just wrong and it should be:  `var j = {"v1":["1","2","3"], "v2":["4","5","6"], "v3":["7","8","9"]};` so you can iterate the properties of `j` directly and skip the array entirely.  If the properties are all meant to be unique and not in any particular order, this is a better way to structure the data.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm new to JS so I am a bit confused on how ot construct my data at the moment. Thanks for bringing this up! I'll consider your suggestion

Comment: There's little benefit to having an array of objects of arrays where each object has a single key that increments. You should just have an array of arrays, and grab the index you want or iterate all of them. `var j = [["1","2","3"], ["4","5","6"], ["7","8","9"]];`

Comment: @Liondancer - there is seldom a reason to use an object with only one property so whenever I see that it's a warning sign that perhaps there's a better way to structure things.

Comment: @jfriend00 I was playing around with JSON.stringify and I want to pass my data to create a key/value pair with the value being something similar to {"v1":["1","2","3"], "v2":["4","5","6"], "v3":["7","8","9"]}

Comment: @Liondancer - see the answer I provided that illustrates the data structure I recommended to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've been discussing in comments, there is seldom a reason to use an array of objects that each only have one property (unless you're using the array to maintain a specific order), so I thought perhaps your problem might be easier if the data was structured like this:

```
var j = {"v1":["1","2","3"], "v2":["4","5","6"], "v3":["7","8","9"]};
```

And, you could then iterate it like this:

```
for (var key in j) {
    console.log("j[" + key + "] = ", j[key]);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qdgzso1g/

Comment: This helped a lot. Less iterations and simpler code. Thanks! =D

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
var  j = [{"v1":["1","2","3"]}, {"v2":["4","5","6"]}, {"v3":["7","8","9"]}];

for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++)
{
    for (var k in j[i]) //do use this if you need to iterate
    {
        if (k === "mySomething")
        {
            //...do your stuff
        }

    }
}
```

**Edit**

less verbose :

```
 for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++)
    {
            if ("mySomething" in j[i])
            {
                //...do your stuff
            }

    }
```

Comment: @Liondancer: Aside from restructuring your data, this solution is more verbose than needed. There's no point to the `for-in` loop. It should just be `if (str in j[i]) { /* do something with j[i][str] */ }`

Comment: @RoyiNamir You helped me with my problem and provided a solution. However jfriend00 pointing out something and also provided a solution. I wish I can give you both check marks but I can't. I'm sorry but jfriend00 gave me a very helpful tip and an solution